# How to save output of a generated text

Tags: python

I am using the following code to generate a text:

```
for i in xrange(300):
    sys.stdout.write(alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())
```

and I would like to know how to store the same text (in the variable `text1`) so that I can use it later in this code:

```
for i in xrange(300):
    text1=sys.stdout.write(alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())

for word in text1:
    fd.inc(word)
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code `alphabet[…]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
text1 = [alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())] for i in xrange(300)]
```

Comment: the OP wants to iterate over `text1` (`for word in text1: ...`), that wouldn't be possible using your solution

Comment: @julio.alegria - it works if `alphabet` contains characters. Now I have changed it to a list of whatever (single characters or strings), so it should work.

Comment: @ eumiro it's actually not working, storing the text in a list makes python regard each character as a distinct word it seems... `for word in text1 : fd.inc(word)` `print fd` `<FreqDist: ' ': 1776, 'e': 1008, 'a': 752, 't': 750, 'n': 604, 'i': 586, 'o': 556, 'h': 542, 's': 528, 'r': 478, 'l': 388, 'd': 312, 'u': 242, 'm': 202, 'w': 192, 'g': 172, 'b': 152, 'p': 152, 'f': 150, 'c': 148, 'y': 120, 'k': 90, 'v': 66, 'q': 12, 'z': 10, 'x': 8, 'j': 4>` Do you know of any way i can store it as actual text? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
text1=sys.stdout.write(alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())])
```

You are just overwriting (changing) the value of the variable `text1`. In adittion, as @eumiro said, you are assigning `text1` to the result of `sys.stdout.write`, which is `None`.

You probably need to store all those values in a list:

```
texts = []
for i in xrange(300):
    texts.append(alphabet[bisect.bisect(f_list, random.random())])

# Do something with each element of the list
for word in texts:
    fd.inc(word)
```

Comment: You don't want to use the output of `sys.stdout.write()`. It returns None.